# Display drop down menu is not working css

Tags: css

I have a weird problem with my project, I tried to create drop down menu,
and I used even simple example from 3 w school and it is not working, here is my code:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span className="span1">Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I saw solutions like `.dropdown:hover +.dropdown-content` and it is not working too.

Comment: seems to be working just fine

Comment: What's not working? Just as @Dejan.S said, working fine here!

Comment: the menu doesn't appear by hover the div(the parent div where is "Mouse over me")

Comment: Tested on FireFox, Chrome and Safari. Voted to close as *not reproducible*.

Comment: As I said it works just fine with hover on the text

Comment: Also works for me in Windows 10 Edge, Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps you have some other code which is affecting it? Also what browsers and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This works & only hovers on text because your *.dropdown* has no padding to it.
In this example, I added padding & pushed down the open menu that you had position absolute on.

Now when space around is hovered, the dropdown is triggered. I also added the :focus-within tag to the css trigger, this allows a user to tab into the parent menu then the open menu.

```css
.dropdown {
  background-color:orange;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  top:60px;
  left:0;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus-within .dropdown-content 
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span className="span1">Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```